# SSL install issue on Apache2 for virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I"m trying to get an ssl cert installed but i'm getting an error when reboot apache.
I get this error

```
Syntax error on line 25 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xxxx.com:
```

Invalid command 'SSLCertificate', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Now the conf for the domain looks like this

```
<virtualhost *:80>

ServerAdmin xxxx@comcast.net
ServerName nearbyregistry.com
ServerAlias www.xxxx.com
DirectoryIndex index.cfm
DocumentRoot "/var/www/nearby"
</virtualhost>

<virtualHost 23.xx.xx.xx:443>
ServerName xxxx.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/nearby"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificate  /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/xxxx.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/www_xxxx_com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/xxx_bundle.crt
</virtualhost>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: And what is in line 25?

Comment: Also, `VirtualHost` should not be all lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

The directive that should be is `SSLCertificateFile`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file
```

and not SSLCertificate